# How set colors for a specific mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, emacs-faces

I'm trying Emacs. I would like to set colors for Eshell. I tried that first with set-foreground-color. But it affects my other modes too.

```
  (add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda ( default ((t (:foreground "#BD8700"))))))
```

But that's not working either. Or it's affecting the colors on other modes/*scratch* too.

Have anyone a suggestion? This is not a duplicate question, because the other answers change the colors of other buffers as well.

Comment: The answer to the linked question only works in situations where the font-lock rule is written so that a variable is evaluated to the face that should be used. This is not the case for the `default` face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to the documentation regarding remapping faces:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

```
(defun my-eshell-mode-faces ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:foreground "#BD8700")))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'my-eshell-mode-faces)
```