# How to override only 'Height' attribute of 'font-lock-function-name-face' for 'verilog-mode'?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How could I override the `Height` of `font-lock-function-name-face` in default theme in `verilog-mode` major-mode?

Hope that value only affect 'verilog-mode'.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example with the `default` face for `eshell-mode` -- just adjust the code for your specific use case:  `(defun my-eshell-mode-faces () (face-remap-add-relative 'default '((:foreground "#BD8700")))) (add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'my-eshell-mode-faces)`.  E.g., instead of `'default`, you would be using `'font-lock-function-name-face`;instead of `:foreground "#BD8700"`, you would be using the `:height ...` attribute and specifying a specific height; instead of the `eshell-mode-hook`  . .    See also the manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

Comment: Here is the link to the related thread, the gist of which is cited above:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28008006/2112489

Comment: A different solution to this is at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/how-to-customize-syntax-highlight-for-just-a-given-mode/2968#2968